# iOS add GMSPolylines with wired phenomena result

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

After adding the polylines to the map, sometime it shows up with wired phenomena. Just like the line has been deformed and rotated. While zooming the map, the lines are shaking.

I recorded a video:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14mY16pv7f2glIc9OIuFVSG7DthGX4Kr9/view

I don't know where it goes wrong because most of the time, the result is OK.
I do add the lines on the main thread.

Comment: I don't know where the `geodesic` property is related, I set it to true

Comment: Did you find solution for this? I am facing same issue

Comment: @PoojaShah forgot to update here, I was using `GKGraphy` to calculate a shortest path from one coordinate to another. When this phenomenon appears, I find out that I forgot to set starting point and it using `{0,0}` coordinate as the starting point, then result node array apparently contains a `{0,0}` coordinate, this point will broke the projection when you add it to `GMSPolyline`s. Thats what I found, wish it could help

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out that was my mistake, using `{0,0}` as the starting point for shortest path finding, close this issue by myself